# How to configure SSL for Apache without storing the private key in a file?

Tags: apache, ssl-certificate

The widely acknowledged configuration of SSL for Apache is to point to the location of Certificate and private key.
Can we configure SSL without storing the private key in a file, rather by keeping it in memory?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Keywhiz](https://square.github.io/keywhiz/) for this:

> Keysync is a Keywhiz client that retrieves secrets from a Keywhiz
>   Server using mTLS with a client certificate and **stores them in tmpfs**.
>
> Presenting **secrets as files** makes Keywhiz compatible with nearly all
>   software. Outside of Keywhiz administration, consumers of secrets only
>   have to know how to read a file.
>
> **Keysync stores all secrets in memory only (via tmpfs) and never**
>   **persists them to disk.** If the server loses power, all secrets will be
>   safely removed from that server.
>
> Keysync's design mitigates a Keywhiz Server outage, since all
>   necessary secrets are stored locally, and can be accessed even if
>   Keysync process is restarted. The full sync of secrets is only
>   necessary in the event of a server reboot.